# PHP Slim Framework routing multi and single resource requests

Tags: php, api, rest, slim

I am trying to create **2 routes** in my Slim application to handle 
**multi** and **single resource** GET requests.

For example:

***/surveys*** will return all surveys

***/surveys/3*** will return survey with id 3

However the following produces a server error:

```
$app->get('/surveys', function ($request, $response, $args) {

     // Code here

});

$app->get('/surveys/{id}', function ($request, $response, $args) {

     // Code here

});
```

Any ideas how can i do this ?

Thank you

Comment: What errors does it produce? And what urls did you try to open?

Comment: "Slim Application Error
A website error has occurred. Sorry for the temporary inconvenience."

The urls are correct.

Comment: Please, show details using the configuration of the [Error Handler](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/handlers/error.html) and show us the error.

Comment: Thanks Davide, using the error handler showed me what the problem was. I am writing an answer right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i had a third route:

```
$app->get('/surveys/count', function ($request, $response, $args) {

    // code here

});
```

which i had paid no mind but it was messing with the second route where the {id} was marching the "count" word. Since i had not enabled the error handler (thanks  Davide Pastore) i couldn't find what the problem was.

I changed the second route to:

```
$app->get('/surveys/{id:[0-9]+}', function ($request, $response, $args) {

    // code here

});
```

and now everything works fine!

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I would write this in the following way:

```php
$app->group('/surveys', function () use($app) {
     $app->get('', function () {

          // Endpoint for '/surveys'

     });

     $app->get('/{id}', function ($id) {

          // Endpoint for '/surveys/{id}'

     });
});
```

Comment: Your code works fine. The problem was elsewhere. I created an answer. Thanks again.